# Is it possible to use other components instead of MvxWindow in MvvmCross?

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross, devexpress-wpf

I am using DevExpres WPF Components and am trying to create a simple WPF-only project.
The docs say that Winow should inherit from `MvxWindow` and UserControl from `MvxWpfView`.
Unfortunately, Devexpess components are already inherited from Window/etc and that approach can't be used.

The only notice about possible solution is a short note in docs that Windows should "be wrapped in presenter" without any details :)

MvvmCross:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MvxWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<views:MvxWindow  
    x:Class="TipCalc.WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxWindow>
```

DevExpress:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : ThemedWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<dx:ThemedWindow
    x:Class="DevExpressMvvmCross.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ShowStatusPanel="False">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</dx:ThemedWindow>
```

Is it possible to use external components with MvvmCross? I would like to stay with dx components because of themes and other cookies.

Comment: Were u able to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use MVVMCross with Devexpress you should create a class which wraps Devexpress's ThemedWindow and implements MVVMCross's three interfaces. IMvxWindow, IMvxWpfView, IDisposable. You can copy the implementation of MvxWindow class. And your wrapper class might look like this:

```
public class DevexpressMvxWindow : ThemedWindow, IMvxWindow, IMvxWpfView, IDisposable
{

    private IMvxViewModel _viewModel;
    private IMvxBindingContext _bindingContext;
    private bool _unloaded = false;

    public IMvxViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => _viewModel;
        set
        {
            _viewModel = value;
            DataContext = value;
            BindingContext.DataContext = value;
        }
    }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bindingContext != null)
                return _bindingContext;

            if (Mvx.IoCProvider != null)
                this.CreateBindingContext();

            return _bindingContext;
        }
        set => _bindingContext = value;
    }

    public DevexpressMvxWindow()
    {
        Closed += MvxWindow_Closed;
        Unloaded += MvxWindow_Unloaded;
        Loaded += MvxWindow_Loaded;
        Initialized += MvxWindow_Initialized;
    }

    private void MvxWindow_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this == Application.Current.MainWindow)
        {
            (Application.Current as MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views.MvxApplication).ApplicationInitialized();
        }
    }

    private void MvxWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) => Unload();

    private void MvxWindow_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Unload();

    private void MvxWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel?.ViewAppearing();
        ViewModel?.ViewAppeared();
    }

    private void Unload()
    {
        if (!_unloaded)
        {
            ViewModel?.ViewDisappearing();
            ViewModel?.ViewDisappeared();
            ViewModel?.ViewDestroy();
            _unloaded = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~DevexpressMvxWindow()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Unloaded -= MvxWindow_Unloaded;
            Loaded -= MvxWindow_Loaded;
            Closed -= MvxWindow_Closed;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in XAML you can use it like this:

```
<customView:DevexpressMvxWindow
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:customView="clr-namespace:MvxSample.Wpf"
    x:Class="MvxSample.Wpf.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000"> 
</customView:DevexpressMvxWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can use other components. Since MVVM Cross is open source, you can take the libraries and attach them to the solution manually without nuget, thus allowing u to add more files and extend its capabilities where ever you need.